# Comparing number data in each key of a map to another numerical value

Tags: c++, iterator, maps

I have created a map which takes in as it's key various event numbers. Each event number then stores a series of numerical values (particle masses - DiLept_M) as its data. I want to iterate through each event number and find the particle mass for each key which is closest to another value. e.g

12345: 3098.5  3099.1 8097.3  4356.5

The event number here is 12345 and the following numbers are all the particle masses. I want to store the event number and particle mass which is closet to 3096 in a new map.

```
 std::map< Int_t, std::vector<Double_t> > MapOfEventsAndMasses;

 for(int i=0; i<tree->GetEntries();i++){ //loop through the data 
 tree->GetEntry(i);

 if(MapOfEventsAndMasses.find(event_number) == MapOfEventsAndMasses.end()){

 std::vector<Double_t> tempVec;  
 tempVec.push_back(DiLept_M); 
 }
 else{
   MapOfEventsAndMasses[event_number].push_back(DiLept_M);
 }



 std::map< Int_t, std::vector<Double_t> >::iterator Iter1; 



   Iter1 = MapOfEventsAndMasses.begin();  


   std::map< Int_t, std::vector<Double_t> >::iterator Iter1_End;

   Iter1_End = MapOfEventsAndMasses.end(); 

   for ( ; Iter1 != Iter1_End; Iter1++){  

Int_t event_number = Iter1->first;  

std::vector<Double_t> DiLept_M = Iter1->second; 




          for( int j=0; j < DiLept_M.size(); i++){


    // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE


      }

   }  //Closing for loop
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) and/or [`std::map::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound)?

Comment: I'm not sure. I assumed this was for the keys rather than the data the keys?

Comment: Oh yeah. Wow, I need to look at what I link instead of assuming :) In that case, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I was thinking of using this approach, however, each key contains data that is all over the place going from say 0 to 5000, the lower and upper bound is going to be different for each key. Surely this is a problem?

Comment: I assumed you already know the key (`event_number`) and just need to find the closest mass in the vector associated with that key. Is this not the case? Do you also need to find the event number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept behind finding the mass closest to a given value from a collection is to iterate the collection and keep updating the smallest seen mass, comparing new masses against the previously smallest seen mass. See the comments in the code for how this is done.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::vector<double>> map { // Data to look through.
            {1, {3098.0, 3097.5, 3099.0, 3094.0}},
            {2, {3098.0, 3093.0, 3095.0, 3094.0}}
    };
    std::map<int, double> results; // Map of events and and their closest masses.
    const double mass = 3096; // Mass to search for.

    for (auto& kv : map) { // Iterates the data.
        const int event_number = kv.first;
        const std::vector<double>& masses = kv.second;

        for (double m : masses) { // Iterates the vector of masses.
            // Attempts to find the element for the event in the results map.
            auto value = results.find(event_number);

            // If unsuccessful, find() returns end() iterator. If unsuccessful,
            // creates a new element with the current mass without comparison
            // (because there is nothing to compare against).
            if (value == results.end()) {
                results.emplace(event_number, m);
            } else if (fabs(mass - m) < fabs(mass - value->second)) {
                // Sets the mass to the current mass if the difference between
                // the current mass and the one to search for is smaller than
                // that of the previously smallest seen mass.
                value->second = m;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto r : results) { // Prints the results.
        std::cout << r.first << ", " << r.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

I didn't re-use any of your code because it is unclear what the first few things do and the bottom half, which is for iterating a map, is heavily simplified with a range-based loop. This also has the advantage of being able to stand on its own for demo purposes.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I had spent time thinking about how to approach the problem and actually came up with your suggestion but wasn't sure how best to implement it. I am super grateful for this and will try and adapt it to my needs. Thank you.

Comment: @AmyTee Consider accepting this answer if you found it helpful.